# how to turn a "list of words" into a variable after config parser grabs them from an ini file

Tags: python, configparser

I have a script that uses config parser to grab a list using config parser and an ini file
using this because the end user will put in his or her own list to use in a sorting script

Example of a part of the config.ini file

```
[ConfigFile]
#L1 Category to Keep
l1cat=('Audio Terminal', 'Communications/Telephone', 'Microphones', 'Speakers', 'Tour Sound')
```

I have this in my script to grab the ini file

```
import configparser
from configparser import ConfigParser
config = ConfigParser()
config.read("SortingConfig.ini")
config.sections()


def variables(section):
    dict1 = {}
    options = config.options(section)
    for option in options:
        try:
            dict1[option] = config.get(section, option)
            if dict1[option] == -1:
                DebugPrint("skip: %s" % option)
        except:
            print("exception on %s!" % option)
            dict1[option] = None
    return dict1
```

the problem portion I am having.... 
is turning the

```
l1cat=('Audio Terminal', 'Communications/Telephone', 'Microphones', 'Speakers', 'Tour Sound')
```

into a useable variable value

further into my script I have this

```
xls_book = xlrd.open_workbook(infilepath, formatting_info = True, encoding_override = "cp1252", logfile = open(os.devnull, 'w'))
sheetname = xls_book.sheet_by_index(0).name

df = pd.read_excel(xls_book, engine = 'xlrd',parse_dates = ['Date'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S').dt.strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M')

## L1 Category keep if isin list
df = df.loc[df['L1 Category'].isin(l1cat)]
```

the Error I get back is
TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]

before it needed to be dynamically changed by the end user, I could literally add l1cat = ('stuff','more stuff','even more stuff') as a regular variable and it worked perfectly

and the reason I am using config parser is because when I compile to an EXE, I need something that the variables can be changed anytime by a config file

I actually need it to work Just as if I had entered the `l1cat = ('stuff','more stuff','even more stuff')`directly into my script

---

The Fixed file looks like this still using teh same ini example as above

```
import configparser
from configparser import ConfigParser
from ast import literal_eval
config = ConfigParser()
config.read("SortingConfig.ini")
config.sections()


def variables(section):
    dict1 = {}
    options = config.options(section)
    for option in options:
        try:
            dict1[option] = config.get(section, option)
            if dict1[option] == -1:
                DebugPrint("skip: %s" % option)
        except:
            print("exception on %s!" % option)
            dict1[option] = None
    return dict1

#The Variable gets Defined
l1catV = literal_eval(config['ConfigFile']['l1cat'])

###Further down in my script as I need to use the variable
xls_book = xlrd.open_workbook(infilepath, formatting_info = True, encoding_override = "cp1252", logfile = open(os.devnull, 'w'))
sheetname = xls_book.sheet_by_index(0).name

df = pd.read_excel(xls_book, engine = 'xlrd',parse_dates = ['Date'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S').dt.strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M')

## L1 Category keep if isin list

##Variable gets used
df = df.loc[df['L1 Category'].isin(l1catV)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)) to parse the values:

```
txt = '''
[ConfigFile]
#L1 Category to Keep
l1cat=('Audio Terminal', 'Communications/Telephone', 'Microphones', 'Speakers', 'Tour Sound')
'''

import configparser
from configparser import ConfigParser
from ast import literal_eval

config = ConfigParser()
#####config.read_string(txt)###### - This portion was incorrect



my_tuple = literal_eval(config['ConfigFile']['l1cat'])

for val in my_tuple:
    print(val)
```

Prints:

```
Audio Terminal
Communications/Telephone
Microphones
Speakers
Tour Sound
```

Comment: I dont understand the txt portion of that example


my `[ConfigFile]
#L1 Category to Keep
l1cat=('Audio Terminal', 'Communications/Telephone', 'Microphones', 'Speakers', 'Tour Sound')` is in a separate file...........
What is the (txt) representing in the config.read_string(txt)

Comment: @soundtechscott the txt variable could be your string you read from your config file. As an example I used only string variable in sample script file (I don't have the INI config file by me)

Comment: the `config.read_string(txt)` section is not needed in my case...all it was doing is causing confusion
other wise it works as I need it to. I'll add teh fix to my main post.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have it working... except for part of the parsing is returning the variable wrong, and I'm not sure what I am missing

in my config.ini

```
[section]
#Color 1
color01 = ('00FCC84E')
cat1 = ('Speakers','Atlas Mic Stands')

#Color 2
color02 = ('00F4426E')
cat2 = ('Audio Mixers/Console')
```

when I use

```
color01V = literal_eval(config['ConfigFile']['color01'])
color02V = literal_eval(config['ConfigFile']['color02'])


cat01V = literal_eval(config['ConfigFile']['cat1'])
cat02V = literal_eval(config['ConfigFile']['cat2'])


print(cat01V)

print(cat02V)
```

one returns with (), the other does not....
what do I need to do to get both returning with ()

```
('Speakers', 'Atlas Mic Stands')
Audio Mixers/Console
```